# How to add a tooltip at the end of the line chart in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a LOESS line and I want to add a tooltip just to label it.

I tried to get the coordinates of the last point of the line, but I get a string and can't retrieve the last point

```
loessRegression_e = d3.regressionLoess()
   .x(d => d.fecha_de_libertad)
   .y(d => d.EXTERNADO)
   .bandwidth(0.20);

var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom);

console.log(valueline(loessRegression_e(data))) // Here is where I tried to get the coordinates of the line, but it is a string, and a pain to slice it

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");

div
   .text(d3.event.pageX + ", " + d3.event.pageY)
   .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 34) + "px")
   .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 12) + "px");

svg.append("path")
   .data([loessRegression_e(data)])
   .attr("class", "line_e")
   .attr("d", valueline);

// Add the x-axis.
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")));

    // Add the y-axis.
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Add the points!
svg.selectAll(".point")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolSquare))
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.fecha_de_libertad) + "," + y(d.COMPURGADO) + ")"; });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind add a mouseover event to display the data point you are hovering over. For example:

```
svg.append("path")
   .data([loessRegression_e(data)])
   .attr("class", "line_e")
   .attr("d", valueline)
   .on( 'mouseover', function( d ) {
       $( '.tooltip' ).text( "(" + d.x + "," + d.y ")" );
       $( '.tooltip' ).show();
     })
    .on( 'mouseout', function( d ) {
        $('.tooltip').hide(); 
     });
```

This assumes you are using jquery but can be easily modified if not.

EDIT: Sorry, I overlooked a few things. You can't add a div directly to an svg without using a foreign object nor can you append text to a circle. So instead you add the div to the html, and with d3 position the div with the bound data. I've attached a (sloppy) minimum working example you can use as reference where I graph a line and show a label according to the last element. DISCLAIMER: I'm sure there is a much more elegant solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .tool-tip {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 10;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
      #svg-container {
        position: relative;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="svg-container" >
      <div class='tool-tip'>WTF</div>
    </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.1/d3.js"></script>

  </body>
  <script>
  let data = [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x':1, 'y': 1}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 3, 'y': 3}]; //made up data
  let width = 500;
  let height = 500;
  let svg = d3.select( "#svg-container" ).append( "svg" ).attr( 'height', height ).attr( 'width', width ).attr( 'id', 'my-svg' )
  let xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain( [0, 4])
                  .range( [ 0, width] )
  let yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain( [0, 4] )
                  .range( [ height, 0] )

  let myline = d3.line()
     .x(d => xscale(d.x))
     .y(d => yscale(d.y))
   svg.append("path")
    .data( [data] )
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", myline);
  let point = svg.selectAll( 'circle' )
    .data( data )
    .enter()
    .append( 'circle' )
      .attr( 'r', 5 )
      .attr( 'cx', function(d) { return xscale( d.x ); })
      .attr( 'cy', function(d) { return yscale( d.y ); })
      .attr( 'fill', 'red' )
      .attr( 'class', 'my-circle' )

  //You start here
  //grab the last data point that you want to add a label to
  let label = svg.select( '.my-circle:last-of-type')

              //use fill method as a hook to bind the data to the label
              .attr( 'fill', function( d ) {

               //get the position to place the label from your data point
                let x = parseFloat($( this ).attr( 'cx' ));
                let y = parseFloat($( this ).attr( 'cy' ));

                //get the raw data point to display
                let x_invert = xscale.invert( x );
                let y_invert = yscale.invert( y );

                //use jquery to set the x and position using offset of 15 - may need to add your
                // svg x and y starting points if somewhere offset from the page
                $( '.tool-tip' ).text( "(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
                $( '.tool-tip' ).css( 'left', (x + 15)  + 'px' );
                $( '.tool-tip' ).css( 'top', (y + 15)  + 'px');
                $( '.tool-tip' ).css( 'visibility', 'visible');

                //return the fill as we only called this to display the label.
                return $( this ).attr( 'fill' );

              })

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I show the tooltip without the mouseover on the last point of the line?

Comment: You want a tool tip only for the last point or do you just want the coordinates of the line so you can display a label that is always displayed? Either way you can select the last element of of a d3 selection using by `d3.select( '.line_e:last-of-type' )` and append the label or add the tooltip only to it.

Comment: I tried to append a div element to the SVG, and put the coordinates in translate, as well as style. The div element is appended to the SVG, but it has no size "0x0", and it doesn't show the text in the coordinate:

    svg.append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .text("EXTERNADO")
      .style("display", "inline");
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(loessRegression_e(data)[199][0]) + "," + y(loessRegression_e(data)[199][1]) + ")")

Comment: If the div has no size so it will not display. Add a height and width attribute to the div. `svg.append( 'div').attr( 'class', 'tooltip').attr( 'height', 200 ).attr( 'width', 200)` or alternatively give to your css file `.tooltip { width: 200; height: 200; }`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it appeared div 0x0, with either option. I tried toggling display: inline and position: absolute, with no results. I will post another question, since it might be a problem of html and css in any case.